# Provision remote nixos box without sending private keys

Tags: ssh, nixos

I am provisioning a nixos instance on AWS. The instance has to download a repositiory from a private github repo. Currently I just run a shell script on the remote box using ssh-forwarding to download the repository. In this way I don't have to copy my private key, which gives me access to the repo, to the remote box.

I would like to change this procedure to be more Nix-like. I want to write a nix expression which downloads the repo and put it in /etc/nixos/configuration.nix. At the same time I don't want to copy my private key to the remote machine. Is this possible? Can nixos-rebuild use ssh forwarding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explore `--build-host` and `--target-host` options of `nixos-rebuild` command. That is, make your local machine a build-machine, and remote one - target. You need root passwordless ssh access to remote though.